# Trying to disable scroll in safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I need to make a page without scrolling in landscape version.
The height of the page to be 100%.

[image]

I've tried everything.
In Safari, I always get to scroll the lower region.
And I get a hidden area.

I can not hide the bottom bar.
And I can not reduce the height. I can not make it smaller than 320.
The browser creates an additional white area at the bottom of the page.

[image]

(Also, i can't use JS)

I will be grateful to anyone reply.

P.S. In the screenshots is not my site, only to show an effect

Comment: I think instead of 100% it may work better if you used 100vh as well as setting the body to overflow:hidden;

Comment: sorry, but it's not working.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible without js. iOS in landscape mode reserves a couple of pixels on top of the document height for the navigation bar(s). Also keep in mind that loading the page when in landscape mode results in the OS's navigation already being visible whereas changing to landscape mode results in a 'fullscreen' view without navigation. There are workarounds for this, but it all requires javascript as of now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can accomplish this. First, you may be able to simply use a table that fills the entire viewport so that each element is then spaced evenly when switching orientations. You could also solve this using simple CSS so you will have more control and have the ability to take advantage of media queries.

See this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0k3m22m/)

First you want to wrap all of your content in a single parent container that fills the entire view. This will prevent content from existing outside of the view.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
        The Menu
    </div>
    <div class="hero">
        The Hero
    </div>
    <div class="head">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is content.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

From here you can then set each element to take up a certain percentage of the parent container so that rescaling recalculates the elements proportions instead of forcing a scroll.

```
.menu, .hero, .head, .content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu {
    top: 0;
    height: 10%;
    background: #eee;
}

.hero {
    top: 10%;
    height: 20%;
    background: #aee;
}

.head {
    top: 30%;
    height: 10%;
    background: #eae;
}

.content {
    top: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    background: #eea;
}
```

Implementing it this way will allow you to have a bit more control of the behavior of each element as the view size changes.